# How to Remove a Git Member from a Project?

Tags: git

I'm facing an issue with Git, and I need some guidance on how to remove another member from my project. In the screenshot attached, you can see that the username of the member is visible. Could someone please walk me through the steps to remove this Git member from the project?

Thanks
[image]

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? The IDE shows the info from the last commit that affected this line (essentially, `git blame`'s output). Why is this an issue for you?

Comment: I'd like to avoid displaying the name of another member who is currently not working on the project. Additionally, I'm unable to change the repository. Is there a way to achieve this without altering the repository itself?

Comment: The only way to (partly) achieve this without altering the commits is to use a `.mailmap` and map that person to "Some user". See the doc [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitmailmap). But not every tool will use it and the commits themselves still will feature this original author. Might be useful depending on your context.

Comment: Just in case, the fact that the person is not working anymore on the project does not mean that the person _did not_ do that.... that is what that line means... after all, it comes from `git blame`.

Comment: What would you want to show instead? Is disabling the IDE extension a viable solution for you?

Comment: This question is illegible.

Comment: If you don't want to see it, disable GitLens, "Inline blame " on "Current line" in extension settings. If you want to hide the information, a `.mailmap` file like proposed could be good enough. But if you want to remove completely the information, you will have to rewrite the git history. My point of view (without understanding your context): prefer the 1st one.

Answer (score 1):

Once a commit is created, it can never be changed again. IDEs usually show the author who last touched a line. Since this change has already happened, the author is fixed. It does not matter if the author left your project or is no longer alive: the change was still done by said author (it's a historic fact).

If you really must "hide" this author, I can see 2 options:

1. Map their name and email to a different, fake name and email in the `.mailmap` file (the mapping file is always taken from `HEAD`, so checking out a different branch or an older commit will show the real name again)
2. Throw away all existing history and rewrite it with a different, fake user for all their changes.

But the question really is: why do you care? This is historic data.

Comment: There is not specific reason behind that , i just wanted to remove the user name which is showing in the IDE.

Comment: Then the question is, which IDE

Comment: I'm using the VS Code